# Nextjs Build fail on Vercel

Tags: next.js, vercel, graphcms

I'm trying to deploy my NextJs app (using GraphCMS) on Vercel. When I build the app on my computer it works fine, I can build and run the app locally but once I try to deploy the same exact app on Vercel it crash with this error

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'document')
> at Object.parseRequestExtendedArgs (/vercel/path0/node_modules/graphql-request/dist/parseArgs.js:37:25)
> at /vercel/path0/node_modules/graphql-request/dist/index.js:422:42
> at step (/vercel/path0/node_modules/graphql-request/dist/index.js:63:23)
> at Object.next (/vercel/path0/node_modules/graphql-request/dist/index.js:44:53)
> at /vercel/path0/node_modules/graphql-request/dist/index.js:38:71
> at new Promise ()
> at __awaiter (/vercel/path0/node_modules/graphql-request/dist/index.js:34:12)
> at request (/vercel/path0/node_modules/graphql-request/dist/index.js:418:12)
> at getPosts (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/104.js:1143:82)
> at getStaticPaths (/vercel/path0/.next/server/pages/post/[slug].js:98:86)
> Build error occurred
> Error: Failed to collect page data for /post/[slug]
> at /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/build/utils.js:959:15
> at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
> type: 'Error'
> }
> error Command failed with exit code 1.

I don't understand where this is coming from.

```
pages/post/[slug].js
```

```
import React from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

import {
  PostDetail,
  Categories,
  PostWidget,
  Author,
  Comments,
  CommentsForm,
  Loader,
} from "../../components";
import { getPosts, getPostDetails } from "../../services";
import { AdjacentPosts } from "../../sections";

const PostDetails = ({ post }) => {
  const router = useRouter();

  if (router.isFallback) {
    return <Loader />;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className="container mx-auto px-10 mb-8">
        <div className="grid grid-cols-1 lg:grid-cols-12 gap-12">
          <div className="col-span-1 lg:col-span-8">
            <PostDetail post={post} />
            <Author author={post.author} />
            <AdjacentPosts slug={post.slug} createdAt={post.createdAt} />
            <CommentsForm slug={post.slug} />
            <Comments slug={post.slug} />
          </div>
          <div className="col-span-1 lg:col-span-4">
            <div className="relative lg:sticky top-8">
              <PostWidget
                slug={post.slug}
                categories={post.categories.map((category) => category.slug)}
              />
              <Categories />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
export default PostDetails;

// Fetch data at build time
export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  const data = await getPostDetails(params.slug);
  return {
    props: {
      post: data,
    },
  };
}

// Specify dynamic routes to pre-render pages based on data.
// The HTML is generated at build time and will be reused on each request.
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const posts = await getPosts();

  return {
    paths: posts.map(({ node: { slug } }) => ({ params: { slug } })),
    fallback: false,
  };
}
```

```
 
 
here is the Graphql query getPosts
```

```
export const getPosts = async () => {
  const query = gql`
    query MyQuery {
      postsConnection {
        edges {
          cursor
          node {
            author {
              bio
              name
              id
              photo {
                url
              }
            }
            createdAt
            slug
            title
            excerpt
            displayedDate
            featuredImage {
              url
            }
            categories {
              name
              slug
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `;

  const result = await request(graphqlAPI, query);

  return result.postsConnection.edges;
};
```

```
 
 

 
   getPostDetails
```

```
export const getPostDetails = async (slug) => {
  const query = gql`
    query GetPostDetails($slug: String!) {
      post(where: { slug: $slug }) {
        title
        excerpt
        featuredImage {
          url
          id
        }
        author {
          name
          bio
          photo {
            url
          }
        }
        createdAt
        slug
        content {
          raw
        }
        categories {
          name
          slug
        }
        displayedDate
      }
    }
  `;

  const result = await request(graphqlAPI, query, { slug });

  return result.post;
};
```

```
 
 

I really don't understand why I can build it locally but not en Vercel, Thanks

Tried to modify queries, turn off fallback and others things that did not work
```

Comment: funny thing is that if I try to deploy it on Netlify, pages/post[slug].js does not throw error but pages/category/[slug].js does the same error ..

Comment: Are you sure the `graphqlAPI` variable is defined when deploying to Netlify? If it depends on an environment variable, make sure to properly configure it in Netlify.

Comment: Hi, after removing everything, started my project with a brand new repo , app and Vercel upload it now works, I don't know where this came from but now it's working. thanks for your help everyone

Comment: I just faced the same issue, and now figured out that it is caused by the `graphqlAPI` variable configuration was set just for `deployment`, but it should be set for `production` and `preview` as well, after adding this setting, the problem solved.